# Vector C++ with your own Class

Tags: c++, macos, xcode4

I tried searching in google but it just shows what I'm not looking for.

I have this class called Student and in my main class I instantiated it to be a vector.

I tried adding this line in my main class

```
vector<Student> students;
students[0].setFirstName("Test");
```

and it throws an error on my Student class

```
void Student::setFirstName(string fname) { firstName = fname; }
```

It says that EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I'm using Xcode in Macintosh

EDIT: I want it to be dynamic that's why I didn't specify the size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I'm sure you know, the expression `students[0]` means that you are trying to access to first item in the `vector`. But in order to *access* the first item, you must first *add* a first item.

Quite simply, add a call to `vector::push_back` before trying to use anything in the vector. Alternatively, declare the vector by

```
vector<Student> students(/*number of default Students here*/);
```

There are also other ways, but just make sure you have what you're trying to use.

To be quite specific, the index you pass to the `[]` operation must satisfy the condition `0 <= index && index < students.size()`. In your case, `students.size() == 0`, so `0 <= index && index < 0`, which is clearly not possible to satisfy.

Comment: 0 doesn't have to be less than `index`.

Comment: @Seth: Thank you, changed it to less than or equal.

Answer (score 5):

When you create your vector, how many elements are in it? None.  And yet you try to access an element right away.  You need to put elements in it first.  Either at initialization, like this:

```
vector<Student> students(10);
```

Or some other method, like [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), or [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize).

Comment: I want it to be dynamic, not static size.

Comment: @lnluis: Okay.  That's not a problem with any of the methods I've mentioned.

Comment: @Inluis in this example it won't be static size, it'll just put 10 default ones in there for you. You're free to add or remove some later.

Comment: @Seth: not sure "10 empty ones" is the best way to phrase that. There will be 10 full-fledged instances of Student inside that vector.

Comment: Correct, so if I have 10 and I added another one using student[i].setFirstName it will throw an error. So better yet I should have just said Student students[30] than use vectors.

Comment: @lnluis: Then there is some relevant code that you're not showing us.  Give a complete minimal example that causes the error.

Comment: The code `student[i].setFirstName` *never ever* adds anything to the vector. Just like with the arrays you mentioned, you can't access elements past the end because *they don't exist*! You must use `push_back` or another inserting method to add to a vector.

Comment: It did add a value if I specified a size. I have 30 input data to be entered. If my vector size is 10 it will throw an error, but if its 30 it won't it will run smoothly. Its like what I said, its just like I just declared a static array with 30 instances of student.

Comment: @InIuis - How is that different from `vector<Student> students(30);`. You should use `std::vector` whenever possible rather than raw arrays.

Comment: Because with 30 students, like you guys said it already have 30 full-fledged instances of Student inside the vector.

Comment: And with an array, it will also have 30 full-fledges instances of Student. With the restriction that you can never add anymore. Try some code like so: `vector<Student> students(10); Student student; for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) students.push_back(student);` In this snippet, you start with only 10 `Student` object in the vector, but after the loop you now have 30 `Student` in the vector, because you called `push_back` 20 times. Methinks you need to read up a little on how vectors work.

Comment: @lnluis: Did you look at the [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) function I showed you?

Comment: Yes, i tried that but what parameters will I pass on the push_back function

Comment: You're correct Ken. You cannot add more therefore it IS NOT DYNAMIC.

Comment: @lnluis: A Student.  You can either construct it before-hand, or you can construct it in the parameter list, like this: `students.push_back(Student());`

Comment: @Inluis: Your array is static, but the *vector is still dynamic*. Check out the code I gave you, that proves it!

Comment: Okay, I tried that it didn't work. It just added one more size of Student from 30 to 31.

Comment: How will you add dynamic in the vector it restricts me because of its size.

Comment: @lnluis: Right, that's what `push_back` does.  It adds one more element to the vector.  That's dynamic.

Comment: @Inluis: Is that not the point? You specifically asked for something which can grow as needed. How can something that grows restrict by its size? If you need more, just call `push_back` some more. Maybe check if `i >= students.size()`, then you must use `push_back` to add more.

Comment: Okay, I see. Sorry im new to C++. Here's the question then. Is there like a ObservableCollection<Student> or List<Student> in C++ where I could just say student[0].Add(new Student( {firstname = bla; })); Just like in C#

Comment: Not even C#'s `Add` works like that. You *either* say `students[0]`, *or* you say `students.Add` - you can't do both at once. To use `[]`, you must first have used `Add`. The same goes for C++ vectors. To use `[]`, you must first use `push_back` (or another inserting method).

Comment: @lnluis: You can't have named parameters in your constructor(or any other function) like that, but other than that, `push_back` is the function you are looking for.  If you have a constructor for Student that takes a string as a parameter and sets the first name with it, then you can do this: `student.push_back(Student("bla"));`

Comment: @Ken my bad, yeah student.add(new student( { firstname = test; })); is there something like this in C++

Comment: @Benj, I have getter and setter in student class how will I pass it on the argument saying that the "bla" will go to the firstname property and not in lastname?

Comment: @lnluis: You can't do that in the constructor.  Like I said, C++ does not support [named parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter).  You'll have to do it after the fact with a call to your setter function.

Comment: @Inluis, write an explicit constructor that accepts arguments, and then use it.

Comment: How is it done in C++ I tried googling but seems cant find it.

Comment: @Inluis: First, create a single Student variable: `Student student`. Then, for the first student, call `student.setFirstName("John");` and `student.setLastName("Doe");`. Then call `students.push_back(student);`. Do the same for the second student: `student.setFirstName("Jane"); student.setLastName("Somebody"); students.push_back(student)`. Repeat until finished.

Comment: Really? I get about 5 million hits for "C++ constructor". @Ken please don't encourage this abuse of getters/setters :(

Comment: Ken, that's a nice answer. I have a question though, can it be just by using Student student then add datas dynamically? no? or i really have to say Student student[30]

Comment: @Karl: It's not an abuse. The alternative is to use constructors, and allocate new instances of Student for each item. That's horribly inefficient, especially if the number grows very large. This is a perfectly fine use case of setters/getters, albeit not their primary purpose. Inluis: I'm confused about this last query. My code does add data dynamically.

Comment: @Ken there's a problem in my situation. I am reading 3 different input files. Last name, first name, grade. So if I am reading the last name first and pushed it back of course first name and grade will be empty. And if I read the second file which is first name, then same thing, last name, grade is empty. IS there a way I can read 3 files at the same time?

Comment: If you know that all the files will have the same number of students, then it is simple. Follow what I gave, but only do it for the first name (assuming you read that file first). You now have a vector full of objects that need last names and grades. You can now use the loop `for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); ++i) students[i].setLastName(lastName);` along with whatever else you need to store the next last name value into `lastName`. Do the same for the grades. So you see, if you don't have the objects yet, you must use `push_back`. Otherwise, you use `[]` to access what's already there.

Comment: You're correct. As much as I want to give you the credit for the answer. Thank you so much Ken !!!

Comment: "allocate new instances"? Only the instances that you were going to use anyway. Construction with parameters is **instead of** default construction followed by setting fields, and is more in keeping with what OO is supposed to be.

Comment: @Karl I definitely understand that constructor are a good way of accomplishing the task. That doesn't make the getter/setter approach any less bad. I'm not saying that you're wrong, I'm just asking that you not say I'm wrong when I'm not. (By the way, yes, you *are* allocating extra instances. You have one temporary created for each Student, each allocated separately. Aside from my first allocation of `student`, all my allocations are done en masse in the vector. Depending on the size of the `Student` class, this *could* make a noticeable difference. But this is tangent to the question).

Comment: Continuing from my last comment... I'd like to point out that C++ isn't purely OO, and also that the OO methodologies which are used in C++ are often different than equivalent techniques in other languages (compare the STL to, say, C#'s standard library. Not even close). So yeah, I'm pretty much trying to say that *your* take on OO is not the only take on OO.

Answer (score 2):

Your `vector` is empty, yet you try to access its first element. Try putting something in the `vector` before accessing its contents.

Answer (score 2):

You are going out of range for your `vector` size. You are trying to access an element which doesn't exist. You can declare its size at initialization.

```
vector<Student> students(SIZE);
```

As a side note, the `setter` methods typically take `const` reference:

```
void Student::setFirstName(const string &fname) { firstName = fname; }
```